ように vs と in delineating quotation
I'm trying to write some practice sentences and I've come across a bit of a dilemma; I can't decide which clause conveys my meaning accurately. I am trying to say "I realized I liked playing basketball":

バスケするのが好きと気づいた
バスケするのが好きように気づいた

From my understanding, と can be a quotation particle; so does that mean, in sentence 1, that I'm essentially saying "'I like playing basketball' I realized"?
If that's the case, then would the second sentence be "I realized I liked playing basketball" (which is what I'm trying to convey)?
Or are both of these sentences the same nuance-wise?

The particle と has some usage. This usage of と is like "that" in a sentence "I realized that I liked playing basketball". For example, 私は明日、雨が降ると思う(I think that it will rain tommorow.).
Your second sentence doesn't make sense.
As for direct quotation, ように isn't used. For example, we don't say "彼は、「明日雨が降る」ように言った。", we say "彼は、「明日雨が降る」と言った。".
